# Can't use pip on macbook

Tags: python, macos, pip

I got this when using pip install.

```
> pip install cognitive_face
Collecting cognitive_face
  Using cached cognitive_face-1.2.5.tar.gz
Collecting requests (from cognitive_face)
  Using cached requests-2.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: requests, cognitive-face
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests'
```

I can find file "python3" and "python3.6" in my `/usr/local/bin` and folder "python3" in`/usr/local/Cellar`.

Also my emacs25 can't do `run-python` and showing:

```
Warning (python): Your ‘python-shell-interpreter’ doesn’t seem to support readline, yet ‘python-shell-completion-native’ was t and "python3.6" is not part of the ‘python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters’ list.  Native completions have been disabled locally.
```

OS Version: `10.12.3`

Comment: `sudo pip install --user cognitive_face`, try that out

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission issue. Use `sudo`

```
sudo pip install cognitive_face
```

Answer (score 0):

You need admin rights. Use `sudo pip …`.